# How to implement #pop for a Linked List in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linked-list

I'm struggling to find a solution for implementing #pop on a LinkedList structure in Ruby. I've currently got my implementation to the point of removing the last element (by setting the `@next_node` element to `nil` on the penultimate node) and returning the new last element, but I need my method to remember and return all of the previous nodes that I've looped through also, and I'm struggling to find a way to do this. Can anybody please help me:

LinkedList example structure;

```
"#<LinkedList:0x000000010ced2508 @head=#<Node:0x000000010ced22b0 @value=13, @next_node=#<Node:0x000000010ced22d8 @value=2, @next_node=#<Node:0x000000010ced2300 @value=25, @next_node=#<Node:0x000000010ced2328 @value=20, @next_node=nil>>>>>"
```

My current #pop implementation:

```
  def pop
    return if head.nil?
    current_node = head
    current_node = current_node.next_node until current_node.next_node.next_node.nil?
    current_node.next_node = nil
    return current_node
  end
```

Updated working method following @tom-lord's answer:

```
def pop
    if head.nil?
      return head
    elsif head.next_node.nil?
      self.head = nil
      return head
    else
      second_last_node = head
      second_last_node = second_last_node.next_node until second_last_node.next_node.next_node.nil?
  
      last_node = second_last_node.next_node
      second_last_node.next_node = nil
      return last_node
    end
  end
```

Comment: Tip: Only `false` and `nil` are not "truthy" in Ruby so you can almost always omit the `.nil?` part.

Comment: Thanks @tadman, noted. In the `if` and `elsif` conditions I need to know whether those 'objects' have `nil` values or not, thus my use of `.nil?`, so I'm not quite sure how you're suggesting that I do without the `.nil?` method. Maybe you're suggesting that it'd be more Ruby like just to negate the tested objects with a `!`/bang, e.g. `if !head` and `elsif !head.next_node`? (apologies if I'm being dim and or confused!)

Comment: In Ruby it's often the case you'll have values that will never, can never be literal `false`, in which case the `nil?` test is extraneous, `if x` is effectively equivalent to `if x.nil?`. If you ever need the inverse condition, it's conventional Ruby to use `unless`. While that might take some getting used to at first, in time it leads to more readable code, like `return unless cond` becomes more natural than `return if !cond`.

Comment: That being said, do yourself a favour and avoid  using `unless ... else ...` and instead just flip the conditions. There are cases where there is no way to express things cleanly, in which case things like `!x` may come into play, but they are thankfully quite rare.

Comment: Thanks @tadman, all noted and will consider in my next writings . Appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your code updated with some comments to recap what you've done:

```
def pop
  # Handles the edge case where the list is empty -- fine.
  return if head.nil?

  # Sets `current_node` to the **SECOND-LAST** node.
  current_node = head
  current_node = current_node.next_node until current_node.next_node.next_node.nil?

  # Deletes the SECOND-LAST node's pointer
  current_node.next_node = nil
  
  # Returns the SECOND-LAST node (???!!)
  return current_node
end
```

There are two things going wrong here:

1. You are returning the second-last node, not the last node.
2. Your code will fail for a linked list that contains exactly 1 node.

I'll focus on fixing (1), and leave (2) as an extension for you to figure out.

```
def pop
  # Handles the edge case where the list is empty -- fine.
  return if head.nil?

  # Using a more descriptive variable name makes it clearer what's happening
  second_last_node = head
  second_last_node = second_last_node.next_node until second_last_node.next_node.next_node.nil?

  last_node = second_last_node.next_node
  second_last_node.next_node = nil
  
  return last_node
end
```

Comment: Thanks @tom-lord, your code breakdown, illustration and re-write helped me get my head around that node traversal and re-setting job. With your help I've updated my method to work and to cater for the only 1 node case (new method appended to original post).